# Angular - QueryList items order is different from the model after changes

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am displaying data in a table using `MatTable` component from `Angular Material` library.

On each table row, I use a directive - `appTableRow` - in order to listen to click and keyboard events.

In the parent component, I use a `QueryList` to obtain all the directives from the view and, because the data is updated, I also use a subscription to obtain the changes in this list:

```js
@ViewChildren(TableRowDirective)
  public rows: QueryList<TableRowDirective> = new QueryList<TableRowDirective>();

public ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.rows.changes
      .pipe(startWith(this.rows))
      .subscribe((newItems: QueryList<TableRowDirective>) => {
        console.log('rows changes:  ', newItems.toArray());
      });

}
```

**The problem:**

When the data model is updated (items are removed / re-added in the array), the QueryList is updated, but the order of the items in the QueryList is different than the order of the items in the data model. The added elements are at the end of the Query List, even if in the data model they are at the beginning.

** Example:**

```
Initial data model : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
Step 1: remove the first 4 items - updated data model -  -> [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10] 
Step 2: re-add the first item - updated data model -  ->[1, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

After step 2, QueryList items are:
Item 5, Item 6, Item 7, Item 8, Item 9, Item 10, Item 1

Stackblitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ig6y8v-2rofcg

(the interesting thing is that, when using a simple list with an `*ngFor`, the QueryList items is always in sync with the data model).